# Java read a encrypted string and decode it

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt a string with a user defined password and then decode it with the string again.

My code:

SecurityManager.java

```
package de.example.org;


import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class SecurityManager {
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";

    private static final SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    private static final Base64.Encoder base64Encoder = Base64.getUrlEncoder();
    private static final SecretKeyFactory factory;

    static {
        try {
            factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static PBEKeySpec generatePBEKeySpec(String password) {
        return new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), generateRandomString(16).getBytes(), 65536, 128);
    }


    public static String generateRandomString(int length) {
        byte[] randomBytes = new byte[length];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(randomBytes);
        return base64Encoder.encodeToString(randomBytes);
    }

    public static String generateEncryptedKey(String password) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(generatePBEKeySpec(password));
        byte[] encodedKey = secretKey.getEncoded();

        // Convert the secretKey to a SecretKeySpec
        Key secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, ALGORITHM);

        // Encrypt the original string
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        String random = generateRandomString(128);
        System.out.println(random);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(random.getBytes());

        return new String(encryptedBytes);
    }

    public static String decryptKey(String encryptedKey, String password) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(generatePBEKeySpec(password));
        byte[] encodedKey = secretKey.getEncoded();

        // Convert the secretKey to a SecretKeySpec
        Key secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, ALGORITHM);

        // Decrypt the encrypted string
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedKey.getBytes());

        return new String(decryptedBytes);
    }


}
```

Executing the function in main:

```
String encrypted = SecurityManager.generateEncryptedKey("123");
String decrypted = SecurityManager.decryptKey(encrypted, "123");
System.out.println(decrypted);
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.prepareInputBuffer(CipherCore.java:887)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:729)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:434)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2206)
    at de.example.org.SecurityManager.decryptKey(SecurityManager.java:66)
    at de.example.org.main.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

I have been sitting on this for hours now, and with bytes I can encrypt it. But since I want to store the encrypted string, so it's still available after a restart, storing the bytes in a file would be less secure AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

My code wasn't actually able to decrypt. This code does the job:

```java
package de.alexx1.birthdaynotf.helper;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

public class SecurityManager {
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";
    private static final int KEY_SIZE = 128;
    private static final int ITERATIONS = 65536;
    private static final int SALT_LENGTH = 16;
    private static final SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    private static final Base64.Encoder base64Encoder = Base64.getEncoder();

    public static String generateRandomString(int length) {
        byte[] randomBytes = new byte[length];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(randomBytes);
        return base64Encoder.encodeToString(randomBytes);
    }

    public static String encrypt(String plainText, String password) throws Exception {
        byte[] salt = generateSalt();
        SecretKey secretKey = generateSecretKey(password, salt);
        byte[] keyBytes = secretKey.getEncoded();
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes(CHARSET));
        byte[] iv = cipher.getIV();
        byte[] encryptedText = new byte[salt.length + iv.length + encryptedBytes.length];
        System.arraycopy(salt, 0, encryptedText, 0, salt.length);
        System.arraycopy(iv, 0, encryptedText, salt.length, iv.length);
        System.arraycopy(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedText, salt.length + iv.length, encryptedBytes.length);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedText);
    }


    public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, String password) throws Exception {
        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText.getBytes(CHARSET));
        byte[] salt = Arrays.copyOfRange(encryptedTextBytes, 0, SALT_LENGTH);
        byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(encryptedTextBytes, SALT_LENGTH, SALT_LENGTH + 16);
        byte[] cipherText = Arrays.copyOfRange(encryptedTextBytes, SALT_LENGTH + 16, encryptedTextBytes.length);
        SecretKey secretKey = generateSecretKey(password, salt);
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
        return new String(decryptedBytes, CHARSET);
    }

    private static SecretKey generateSecretKey(String password, byte[] salt) throws Exception {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, ITERATIONS, KEY_SIZE);
        return factory.generateSecret(spec);
    }

    private static byte[] generateSalt() {
        byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_LENGTH];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }


}
```